# Is it possible to chroot sftp service as unprivileged user?

Tags: linux, chroot, openssh

I currently have an sftp-only sshd service running as an unprivileged user that works fine. When adding
`ChrootDirectory %h`
to the separate user_sshd_config, the user is immediately disconnected after successfully authenticating with publickeys and the error log shows the following:
`fatal: server lacks privileges to chroot to ChrootDirectory [postauth]`
The target directory is owned by the user running the process.

Is it possible to run a chroot'd sshd service running as an unprivileged user, or does the service have to have root permissions to perform a chroot operation?
Let me know if more information is needed, but from what I can see, all relevant information has been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, `chroot(2)` must be called as `root`.

Comment: bummer, figured as much. thanks for the reply